# asp.net mvc c# dynamic checkboxes getting controller value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have the dynamic multiple  checkbox controls generated in the view. what is the best way to get their value in the controller?.There can be multiple values for multiple checkboxes.

Did any one notice that using html.checkbox there is a hidden field added with the already created checkbox? i notice it with firebug ,wonder why

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of names of the dynamically generated checkboxes, you can extract the values like this:

View:

```
<%foreach (string checkBoxName in Model.dynamicCheckboxList)                      
{%>
    <%=Html.CheckBox(checkBoxName)%>
<%}%>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult controllername(FormCollection form)
{
     foreach(string checkBoxName in dynamicCheckboxList)
     {
           var value = form[checkBoxName];
           //process value here
     }
}
```